# How to pass/get radio button value? Angular2 + Material?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

HTML FILE

```html
<mat-radio-group [(ngModel)]="selectRankExport">
                        <div class="row ">
                           

                            <mat-label class="col-md-2">Rank 1</mat-label>

                            <mat-radio-button
                                class="col-md-2"
                                value="1"
                            ></mat-radio-button>

                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <mat-label class="col-md-4"></mat-label>
                            <mat-label class="col-md-2">Rank 2</mat-label>
                            <mat-radio-button
                                class="col-md-2"
                                value="2"
                            ></mat-radio-button>
                         
                        </div>
                        <div class="row ">
                            <mat-label class="col-md-4"></mat-label>
                            <mat-label class="col-md-2">Rank 3</mat-label>
                            <mat-radio-button
                                class="col-md-2"
                                value="3"
                            ></mat-radio-button>
                          
                        </div>
                        <div class="row ">
                            <mat-label class="col-md-4"></mat-label>
                            <mat-label class="col-md-2">Rank 4</mat-label>
                            <mat-radio-button
                                class="col-md-2"
                                value="4"
                            ></mat-radio-button>
                           
                        </div>
                    </mat-radio-group>
                    <button
                                mat-button
                                mat-raised-button
                                color="primary"
                                
                                
                            >
                                Save
                            </button>
```

TS FILE

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material';



/**
 * @title Basic use of `<table mat-table>`
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'table-basic-example',
  styleUrls: ['table-basic-example.css'],
  templateUrl: 'table-basic-example.html',
})
export class TableBasicExample {
selectRankExport = '1';
    rankOne;
    rankTwo;
    rankThree;
    rankFour;

    seeValue(){
      console.log('print')
    }
}
```

i want to print every radio button value i.e if u select radio button one then in console.log should print 1 value if i select radio button 2 then in console log the value should be 2... how to print radio button value in console or how to store radio button value or how to get radio button value?

HERE it is my StackBlitz link --- >https://stackblitz.com/edit/radio-button-1238719823791

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

HTML Code:

```
<mat-radio-group [(ngModel)]="selectRankExport" (ngModelChange)="setValue()">
    <div class="row ">
        <mat-label class="col-md-2">Rank 1</mat-label>
        <mat-radio-button class="col-md-2" value="1"></mat-radio-button>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <mat-label class="col-md-4"></mat-label>
        <mat-label class="col-md-2">Rank 2</mat-label>
        <mat-radio-button class="col-md-2" value="2">

    </mat-radio-button>
    </div>
    <div class="row ">
        <mat-label class="col-md-4"></mat-label>
        <mat-label class="col-md-2">Rank 3</mat-label>
        <mat-radio-button class="col-md-2" value="3"></mat-radio-button>

    </div>
    <div class="row ">
        <mat-label class="col-md-4"></mat-label>
        <mat-label class="col-md-2">Rank 4</mat-label>
        <mat-radio-button class="col-md-2" value="4"></mat-radio-button>

    </div>
</mat-radio-group>
<button mat-button mat-raised-button color="primary">
        Save
</button>
```

In your ts file:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material';

/**
 * @title Basic use of `<table mat-table>`
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'table-basic-example',
  styleUrls: ['table-basic-example.css'],
  templateUrl: 'table-basic-example.html',
})
export class TableBasicExample {
    selectRankExport = '1';
    rankOne;
    rankTwo;
    rankThree;
    rankFour;

    setValue(){
      console.log(this.selectRankExport)
    }
}
```

[StackBlitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/radio-button-1238719823791-6tznqq)